# Speed up difflib to find get_close_matches() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 18,000 rows (keywords) that needs to be searched in dataframe of 300,000 rows (sentences).

I am using `difflib.get_close_matches()` to do it but it is extremely slow. I am using the following method.

```
for searchIndex,searchrow in 18K.iterrows():
    for mainIndex,mainrow in 300K.iterrows():
```

Comment: 18K * 300K = 5400M = 5.4G loop operations. It's expected to be slow.

Comment: `difflib.get_close_matches` accepts a list of words for matching, so maybe try passing all elements in `300K` as the second parameter, rather than a nested loop?

Comment: @dibery I did the calculation :).  I will try passing all searching words as a list but wonder about the output. Will I get to know Hello matching words are Helo, Hello etc..

Comment: It results in error IndexError: list index out of range.  Works one I use one list and one keyword but only issue is speed.